# Convert string containing numbers separated by spaces into list of doubles c#

Tags: c#, string, list, numbers, double

I have this string `05201 05594 05453 05521 05330 04952 04984 04526`, and I need to turn it into an array of doubles.

**How can I do so, without including the extra space at the end?**

---

**EDIT:** Instead of turning into an array of doubles, I need to skip that step and add it to the end of an existing list of doubles

Comment: do you want it like 0.5021 or just exact your values ?

Comment: Exact values are needed.

Comment: All these excellent answers will work for you, then just `AddRange` to your existing list and pass it the results from (wudzik's ;) one of the answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var splitted = yourString.Split(new []{" "}, 
                                          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
existingListOfDoubles.AddRange(splitted.Select(double.Parse));
```

Try it at [ideone](http://ideone.com/Rswv1a). Edited to match question

Answer (score 3):

Split and convert. This assumes that your string contains only numbers.
Use a `List<double>` instead of an array for more advanced functionality

```
string inputString = "05201 05594 05453 05521 05330 04952 04984 04526 ";
string[] results = inputString.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<double> d = new List<double>();
d.AddRange(results.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x)));
```

Now if you want to store in an array you just convert back the `List<double>` to an array

```
double[] values = d.ToArray();
```

Instead if you want to append these results to an existing list of doubles

```
List<double> currentValues = new List<double>() {5345, 4213};
currentValues.AddRange(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "05201 05594 05453 05521 05330 04952 04984 04526";
var result = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string stringList = "05201 05594 05453 05521 05330 04952 04984 04526 ";   
var doubles = stringList.TrimEnd().Split(' ').Select(s => double.Parse(s)).ToList();
```